# how to overwrite a particular data in file using c++

Tags: c++

I am facing problem while overwriting a file at a particular position in C++. I have opened my file using `ios::app|ios::binary`. Then I seek to that position which I want to overwrite. But instead of overwriting it, I append from the end of the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you think `ios::app` does?

Comment: remove the ios::app option?

Comment: About `ios_base::app` (`§27.5.3.1.4`): `seek to end before each write`

Comment: if remove it then it will overwrite whole file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427698/write-to-the-middle-of-an-existing-binary-file-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify `ios::in` as well as `ios::out`. It overwrites if you have only `ios::out` (default in `ofstream`). As stated `ios::app` means data is written to the end of the file, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your file with ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary. After that you should use seekp() to seek to the desired position of the file before the write.

Comment: Using only `ios::out` will empty the file, you need `ios::in` to prevent the file from being emptied (or `ios::app` if you want to write only to the end.